# read File from relative path using FileInputStream

Tags: java, path, relative-path, fileinputstream

I want to read a file from a relative path. 
I've tried the following code

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(".//Audio//w1.wav");
```

Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\Audio\w1.wav (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I also tried to specify the path as "Audio/w1.wav", "Audio//w1.wav" but it does not work.

How can I get the system to find the file?

Comment: `AudioStream swar=new AudioStream(in);` What the heck is an `AudioStream`? Use an `AudioInputStream` instead. it can take input from any stream, including one from an URL.

Comment: General tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be a wrong path. To track that down, start with figuring out where `.` is. To do so run:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

This should print the entire path you're in, beginning with `c:\` or `/` depending on your os.

Now take a look at that folder in the explorer, is everything you expect to be in `.` in that folder?

- If yes: check for typos and switch between `\` and `/` and check file access permissions?
- If no: adjust your path or move the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can so something like this to get the file,

```
ClassLoader resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
URL path = this.getClass().getResource("/Audio/w1.wav");

//Since you have the path you can get the file as you want
//To get the file,  
File file = new File(path.getFile());
```

Comment: ClassLoader resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            URL path = resource.getResource("/Audio/w1.wav");
            
            in=new FileInputStream(new File(path.getFile()));
            swar=new AudioStream(in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(swar);

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Exception is at --> in=new FileInputStream(new File(path.getFile()));

What to do?

Comment: First try to print the path, see if you are at right path, try getting the file and see if you can and I am not sure what is your in variable.

Comment: //  am not sure what is your in variable. //

--> ClassLoader resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader(); URL path = resource.getResource("/Audio/w1.wav"); InputStream in=new FileInputStream(new File(path.getFile())); AudioStream swar=new AudioStream(in); AudioPlayer.player.start(swar);

I want to play audio file having relative path. Please help

Comment: `File file = new File(path.getFile());` That won't be a valid `File` if the URL points to a web site or (more likely) an embedded resource (a resource in a Jar file).